# WP8 platform on Cordova cannot run: CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-cli

I already built the same application on iOS and Android, but now I'm trying to build it for Windows Phone 8. The problem is that when I attempt to run it on the emulator I get this error:

`CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed :: www/www/index.html`

And the application doesn't run, it only displays a black screen.

I already updated Cordova to 5.0.0, and recreated the platform trice, but I still get the same error.

These are steps to reproduce the error:

1. `cordova platform add wp8`
2. open the VS Solution project `project.sln`
3. run as `Emulator 720p` (or any one, I already tried everyone)

Or just run: `cordova emulate wp8` and the emulator shows the splash-screen and then the black screen.

I'm on Windows 8 Enterprise and using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 v12.0.31101.00 Update 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova 5.0.0 hasn't been tested on VS 2013 Update 4. If you want to use 5.0, you should download [VS 2015 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs) and refer to [Known Issues section for Cordova 5.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-known-issues-vs) . Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2015. Any help?

Comment: Same issue with VS 2015 and cordova 6.3.1